# ln -s with a path relative to pwd

Tags: bash, shell, symlink, ln

I'm trying to create a bunch of symbolic links, but I can't figure out why this is working

```
ln -s /Users/niels/something/foo ~/bin/foo_link
```

while this

```
cd /Users/niels/something
ln -s foo ~/bin/foo_link
```

is not.

I believe it has something to do with `foo_link` linking to foo in `/Users/niels/bin` instead of `/Users/niels/something`

So the question is, how do I create a symbolic link that points to an absolute path, without actually typing it?

For reference, I am using Mac OS X 10.9 and Zsh.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The easiest way to link to the current directory as an absolute path, without typing the whole path string would be

```
ln -s "$(pwd)/foo" ~/bin/foo_link
```

The `target` (first) argument for the `ln -s` command works relative to the symbolic link's location, not your current directory. It helps to know that, essentially, the created symlink (the second argument) simply holds the *text* you provide for the first argument.

Therefore, if you do the following:

```
cd some_directory
ln -s foo foo_link
```

and then move that link around

```
mv foo_link ../some_other_directory
ls -l ../some_other_directory
```

you will see that `foo_link` *tries* to point to `foo` in the directory it is residing in. This also works with symbolic links pointing to relative paths. If you do the following:

```
ln -s ../foo yet_another_link
```

and then move `yet_another_link` to another directory and check where it points to, you'll see that it always points to `../foo`. This is the intended behaviour, since many times symbolic links might be part of a directory structure that can reside in various absolute paths.

In your case, when you create the link by typing

```
ln -s foo ~/bin/foo_link
```

`foo_link` just holds a link to `foo`, relative to its location. Putting `$(pwd)` in front of the target argument's name simply adds the current working directory's absolute path, so that the link is created with an absolute target.

Comment: *"...helps to **imagine** that the created symlink simply holds text...."*  Isn't this the literal truth?

Comment: It is. Perhaps I could change **imagine** to "know" or "understand".

Comment: Perhaps I have gotten myself confused (again). It seems where you say "target" you mean "source". The `source_file` (first) argument is where the link points, which is verbatim what you enter on the command. The `target_file` (second) argument becomes the name of the link unless what you enter is a directory, in which case the link name is the same as the basename of the `source_file` but placed in the directory `target_file`.

Comment: Y̶o̶u̶'̶r̶e̶ ̶r̶i̶g̶h̶t̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶'̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶m̶i̶s̶t̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶.̶ ̶C̶r̶a̶z̶y̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶d̶i̶d̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶ ̶c̶a̶u̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶s̶o̶o̶n̶e̶r̶.̶ ̶F̶i̶x̶i̶n̶g̶.̶ No, the answer was right. By the `ln` manpage, `target` is the first argument (where the link points *to*) whereas the second argument is simply referred to as the `link` (`source` is not mentioned).

Comment: In linux (gnu ln) the man page calls the first argument `target` and the second `link` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html). But in BSD (including OS X) the first is called `source` and the second `target` (https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ln). Quite confusing.

Answer (score 9):

Using the `-r` (`--relative`) flag will make this work:

```
ln -sr foo ~/bin/foo_link
```

Comment: Beware that `-r` is a GNUism, i.e. non POSIX so won't work in the OP case as the standard OS X `ln` command is BSD based.

Answer (score 4):

To save some typing, you can do

```
ln -s "$PWD"/foo ~/bin/foo_link
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [realpath](http://man.he.net/?topic=realpath&section=all)

```bash
cd /Users/niels/something
ln -s "$(realpath foo)" ~/bin/foo_link
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
 $ cd /Users/niels/something
 $ ln -s ./foo ~/bin/foo_link
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't do the trick.